# Can I use Apache Felix with WAS 8.5

Tags: apache-felix, websphere-8

I have very little experience with Apache Felix, however, I am trying to run JIRA on my local Websphere 8.5 install and Felix complains about javax.servlet being >= 2.4. I can't change this so I am curious, Is there a newer version that will work or is there a way that I can install an application that uses Felix inside WAS 8.x?

Answer (score 0):

So far the answer appears to be no, making JIRA integration unlikely without the source code (not paying if I can't demo) and the replacement of the Felix dependency.